# How does FindContours cycle through the image? OpenCV 2.3

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing

We are writing a program that takes input from a webcam, substracts all color except the green values, finds the seperated BLOBs and numerates them. Eventually, this will be used as an input for a video game, but that is irrelevent right now.

The code in question is not the code that actually does all of this, but instead, a rewritten segment of the code to test how FindContours actually works. 
Usually, with imageprocessing, we have been tought that the image is read from top left to bottom right, but after some testing, it seems that it does the exact opposite, starting at the lower right corner and moving to the upper left!

So the question here is: In which order does FindContours find it's Contours? Am I right in my assumption or is it my own code confusing me?

Input: [Blobtest06](http://i32.photobucket.com/albums/d37/Ethalox/Blobtest06.png)

["Components" window](http://i32.photobucket.com/albums/d37/Ethalox/Components.jpg)

[Console](http://i32.photobucket.com/albums/d37/Ethalox/Console.jpg)

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <Windows.h> //for sleep function

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void IsolateGreen(Mat mIn, Mat& mOut)
{
Mat inImg (mIn.rows, mIn.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(1,2,3));
inImg.data = mIn.data;
Mat channelRed (inImg.rows, inImg.cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat channelGreen (inImg.rows, inImg.cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat channelBlue (inImg.rows, inImg.cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat outImg[] = {channelRed, channelGreen, channelBlue};

int fromTo[] = { 0,2, 1,1, 2,0};
mixChannels( &inImg, 1, outImg, 3, fromTo, 3);

mOut = (channelGreen) - (channelRed + channelBlue);

threshold(mOut, mOut, 5, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

erode(mOut, mOut, Mat(), Point (-1,-1), 1);
dilate(mOut, mOut, Mat(), Point(-1,-1), 2);

}

void FindContours(Mat& mDst, Mat mGreenScale, vector<vector<Point>>& vecContours, vector<Vec4i>& vecHierarchy, Mat img)
{
//This is empty at all times. We need it to avoid crashes.
vector<Vec4i> vecHierarchy2; 

// mGreenScale = mGreenScale > 1; //// MIGHT be entirely unneeded 

mDst = img > 1;
findContours( mGreenScale, vecContours, vecHierarchy,
        CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

/* Colors, in order:
1st. = Red
2nd. = Dark red
3rd. = Purple
4th. = Blue
5th. = Baby blue
6th. = Green
7th. = Olive green
8th. = Dark green
*/

int aRed[] = {255, 100, 128, 0, 191, 0, 202, 0};
int aGreen[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 239, 255, 255, 100};
int aBlue[] = {0, 0, 128, 255, 255, 0, 112, 0};
string sColor[] = {"Red", "Dark red", "Purple", "Blue", "Baby blue", "Green", "Light green", "Dark green"};

//its important that we check if there is anything in vecHierarchy (else) {crash} :P
//function drawContours cannot handle an empty vedHierarchy
if (vecHierarchy != vecHierarchy2)
{
    // iterate through all the top-level contours,
    for(int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = vecHierarchy[idx][0] )
    { 
        // draw each connected component with its own FIXED color
        Scalar color( aBlue[idx], aGreen[idx], aRed[idx] );
        drawContours( mDst, vecContours, idx, color, /*1*/ CV_FILLED, 8, vecHierarchy );
        cout << vecContours[idx][0] << " - - " << sColor[idx] << " - - Index: " << idx << endl;
    }
}
cout << "Objects: ";
cout << vecContours.size();
cout << endl;

}




int main()
    {
    Mat img = imread("Blobtest06.png");
    Mat mGreenScale;

    //These next 5 instances ties to contourfinding                 
    cvtColor(img, mGreenScale, CV_8UC3); //sets the right rows and cols
    vector<vector<Point>> vecContours; //points to each pixel in a contour
    vector<Vec4i> vecHierarchy; //A hierarchy for the functions
    Mat mDst = Mat::zeros(mGreenScale.rows, mGreenScale.cols, CV_8UC3); //mDst image


    IsolateGreen(img, mGreenScale);
    FindContours(mDst, mGreenScale, vecContours, vecHierarchy, img);

    namedWindow( "Components", 1 );
    imshow( "Components", mDst );
    namedWindow( "Source", 1 );
    imshow( "Source", mGreenScale );

    waitKey();  
    return 0;
    }
```

PS: Sorry for horrible syntax. The site is being difficult and it's just about lunchtime.

Answer (score 5):

If you care about the details of implementation of OpenCV, which is an Open Source library by the way, you can always [download the source](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2?r=http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.3.1/&ts=1321535597&use_mirror=ufpr) and read it yourself.

**Warning**: the C++ API uses the C API for some things, including `FindCountours()`. So if you check the file: `modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp` line **1472** you'll see the C++ implementation of this function:

```
1472 void cv::findContours( InputOutputArray _image, OutputArrayOfArrays _contours,
1473                    OutputArray _hierarchy, int mode, int method, Point offset )
1474 {
1475     Mat image = _image.getMat();
1476     MemStorage storage(cvCreateMemStorage());
1477     CvMat _cimage = image;
1478     CvSeq* _ccontours = 0;
1479     if( _hierarchy.needed() )
1480         _hierarchy.clear();
1481     cvFindContours(&_cimage, storage, &_ccontours, sizeof(CvContour), mode, method, offset);
1482     if( !_ccontours )
1483     {
1484         _contours.clear();
1485         return;
1486     }
```

calling `cvFindContours()`, which is from the C API, defined in this same file on line **1424**.

The **scanning process** itself is described on `cvFindNextContour()`, located at line **794**:

```
793 CvSeq *
794 cvFindNextContour( CvContourScanner scanner )
795 {
```

and you can clearly see:

```
824     for( ; y < height; y++, img += step )
825     {
826         for( ; x < width; x++ )
827         {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - But! I can't seem to grasp the answer, entirely. I can see the way the math would work but it doesn't give any insight to the direction. Which pixel does it start at and where does it end? I'm a bit of a beginner, on a sidenote, so bear with me. :)